# Is it possible to run particular block code after receiving push message(APN) without any user input interaction

Tags: ios

- I want to fetch data from my server continuously with the interval of 5 or 10 minutes.I know ios not supports long running background operations.So I trying other solution using PUSH Notification.
- Is it possible to run particular block code after receiving push message(APN) without any user input interaction? Because I need to receive push notifications and store in Local SQlite database continuously. Then I display data fetching from local DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to run particular block code after receiving push message(APN) without any user input interaction?

No. The user needs to explicitly tell iOS to hand over the push notification to the app, by tapping the non-cancel button when the push notification is received, which causes your app to be launched (if not running already) and brought into the Active state.

Comment: so push notification is choice for my task(fetch data from my server continuously with the interval of 5 or 10 minutes in background). Also in some websites and blogs,they run long background tasks by dummy VOIP or GPS(as ios supports long running oprations for these apps only). If do like this, can I publish my Application to app store? ios team checks our source code?

Comment: The minimum interval for a VoIP keep-alive handler is 10 minutes. If by GPS you are talking about location services, then if you are getting location updates but your app but your app is not a "location" app, Apple will reject your app. If you use the 'voip' background mode but your app is not a VoIP app, Apple will reject your app.

Answer (score 1):

when ever you get a push notification from APNS program controle will come to `appDelegate` method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

Here you can do what ever you want.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.

Actually, it is technically possible to run tasks in the background, but this will get your app rejected. Others have tried: http://tapbots.com/blog/pastebot/pastebot-music-in-background